# My custom fields are not visible on Contact's Activity Log

Tags: contacts, logging

I try to show (first for the admin user) all changes for a contact. That works on Contact's Activity Log page. I can see the date and time of modifying my custom fields, but the old and the new values are not shown. In the databases log table for the custom field are the changes logged.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled detailed logging (this is disabled by default)?

If no, you can enable this from the Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.) menu option -

/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

This feature records a full history of all changes made.

Please note the below before this feature is enabled -

Detailed logging (aka "logging") allows you to maintain a full history of all changes made to everything in CiviCRM. It's a powerful feature which is turned off be default — because it's a bit overkill for most organizations, and it comes with some downsides too.

Full details can be found [HERE](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/logging/)

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. All changes are stored in the database tables named "log_[table_name]" (I can list them via phpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 0):

Does the user has the permission to view the 
report `Contact Logging Report (Summary)`?

[image]

Comment: I try to see all field's change with the admin user, witch has full access (all flags are set) on the Drupal's permission page (`admin/people/permissions`).